# Additional vertice on Object Mode

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, object-mode

I just started with Blender and found some wired problem - on Object Mode I see a vertice, that i cant notice in Edit Mode. I have no idea why it happend and how to fix it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is the so called "origin" of the object, it's not a vertex.

Comment: Hello :). As @joshsanfelici pointed out, it's the [Object Origin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html). It determines object's location in the 3D space and can act as a pivot point.

Comment: You can also hide verts in Edit Mode by pressing H and unhide with Alt+H. May be you hide it.